# Show done plot in a widget

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt

I have build a GUI with Qt Designer and have a code which generates a 3D-Model using matplotlib. When I run this code it opens a new window which allows me to interact with that model.
I want to have this window inside a widget in my GUI. The idea is that  I have 3 buttons with 3 different models. And after one gets clicked the chosen model will be displayed.

Basically, I dont know how to connect the plot to the widget.

I tried to promote the QWidget to a mplwidget following this guide:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2C5VnE9wPhk

But it doesnt go indepth and I only found this video.

also, I dont know if that is an issue, I am using matplotlib.pyplot.

```
 X = 2D-Array
 Y = 2D-Array
 Z = 2D-Array #(generetad using numpy.mehsgrid)
 fig = plt.figure()
 ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
 ax.set_xlabel('X-Achse')
 ax.set_ylabel('Z-Achse')
 ax.set_zlabel('Y-Achse')
 ax.plot_surface(X, Z, Y, color='gray')
 plt.show()
```

is how I get my window for my model

```
class MatplotlibWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.sollmodell)
        # self.ui.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.openFileDialogISTI)
        # self.ui.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.openFileDialogSOLLA)
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
```

this is my GUI code. below there I have my method which is connected to the button. basically it will run the code above but nothing happens (not even a pop up window).

Expected: Model inside the Widget, able to change via mouseclick
Actual: blank widget with x and y axis going from 0 to 1 and shwowing nothing

Comment: [Here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html) is how you can embedd a matplotlib figure in a PyQt widget.

Comment: Hello, thanks for that link. I wonder how I never stumbled upon  it.

 Could you tell me the difference between static and dynamic canvas? I think one is for plots that dont changeright?

And do I need to make an own .py file for the widget alone like mtpwidget before or can i just add this class to my code which creates my gui?

thanks in advance!

Comment: The example adds two figures and their respective canvas are given those names. There is no other difference and you could call them Max and Moritz instead. A single file for the complete code would be enough.